# C# TCP Client having trouble listening to Server and updating GUI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tcp, tcplistener

I have a GUI with 2 buttons and a text box. Button1 starts a server and has it listen for clients. Button 2 sends a connection request to the server and starts to listen for anything the server will send to the client (responses). Although w/ my current code when the Server sends the reply and I try to write it to a text box the whole system hangs.

Code as seen below:
Server Class:

```
class Server
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;


    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //create a thread to handle communication 
            //with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }
    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                break;
            }

            //message has successfully been received
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Client!");
            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
        }
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
    public Server()
    {
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        this.listenThread.Start();
    }
}
```

GUI class:

```
    private void buttonServerStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server Myserver  = new Server();
    }

    //Greet the Server and listen for response...
    private void EthStartB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000);

        client.Connect(serverEndPoint);

        NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Server!");

        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        clientStream.Flush();
        //start listening            
        this.ClientListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                break;
            }

            //message has successfully been received
            tb_recieved.Clear();
            tb_recieved.Text=encoder.GetString(message,0,bytesRead);
        }
    }
    TcpListener ClientListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000);
    private void EthEndB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 frmT = new Form3();
        frmT.Show();
    }       

}
```

The issue is when `private void EthStartB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` calls the code line of `tb_recieved.Text=encoder.GetString(message,0,bytesRead);`

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: The commands that update the GUI will need to occur in the UI Thread otherwise they throw cross thread exceptions, which your code might be eating

Comment: I can use Control.Invoke to avoid this yes?

Comment: @AydinAdn This is WinForms why? (sorry for late response. was busy with different project)

Comment: @DarthSheldon, YK1 hit the nail on the head, so to quote him...

"Move the receive logic on a new thread and set the textbox content using Control.Invoke or Dipatcher.Invoke depending on whether you are on WinForms or WPF - and do that only if you do have some content in the message to be written to textbox."

I asked because it affects how you can get back on to the UI thread :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program hangs because you have a `while(true)` loop in `EthStartB_Click` which runs on UI thread. `clientStream.Read` call will block UI thread.

Move the receive logic on a new thread and set the `textbox` content using `Control.Invoke` or `Dipatcher.Invoke` depending on whether you are on WinForms or WPF - and do that only if you do have some content in the `message` to be written to textbox.

There also another issue, since you have the `tcpClient.Close()` **outside** the `while` loop on the server, neither client nor server will disconnect. Both will block on their respective `stream.Read` calls.

Since you are running both client and server on same machine, that `TcpListener ClientListener` is not required and will not play well with the server already listening on the same port.

Comment: sorry for late response, got pulled off onto a different project last week. The reason I have the listener is because this server was put in place just to test the client code. The server code will be in a MicroController in the actual project. I just wanted  to get TCP working so server could send/receive w/o error first